# Show Jenkins test results in Eclipse JUnit view

Tags: eclipse, junit, jenkins

Is there a way to import the Jenkins JUnit test results into Eclipse's JUnit view? I found the 'Import from URL...' in Eclipse. Is there a way in Jenkins to create the necessary XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what I really wanted is provided by the Mylyn's Hudson/Jenkins connector.

Install it using `Install new features...` in Eclipse using the Mylyn's update site

- for Eclipse Juno: http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/juno
- for Eclipse Kepler: http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/kepler

and tick the appropriate Mylyn build connector.

[image: installation screenshot]

Once installed open the appropriate view using `Window > Show View > Others` and selecting `Mylyn > Builds`

[image: show view screenshot]

Work's like a charm! You can monitor and start Hudson/Jenkins builds, and view the build console and JUnit results directly in Eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest test result file directly from `workspace` folder (You could look your last build file in `/jenkins/jobs/XXXXXXX/builds/YYY` to know where it lies).

But for previous builds I'm afraid Jenkins keeps its own file with its own structure under `/jenkins/jobs/XXXXXXX/builds/YYY`.

So unless you have a task copying the result for you somewhere, I don't think you'll be able to import them in eclipse.

Comment: Which URL would I use for the workspace folder? I would need a URL to expose the test results of the test suite itself and no html output.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that using ANT Junit reports can be created with Jenkins. That XML file can then be taken as URL then.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the usage of the Mylyn connector, in Jenkins one needs to specify "**Publish JUnit test result report**" in the "Post-build Actions" section of the project's configuration page. The parameter is the pattern for the xml files of the tests results, or pattern for the xml file of the JUnitReport task if it is used.

That was the thing that worked for me. I Don't know if that option had existed back then though.